# Passing string variable to forcats::fct_reorder

Tags: r, tidyverse, forcats

Any idea how to pass a string sorting variable to `fct_reorder`?

```
require(dplyr)
require(forcats)
require(ggplot2)

order_var = 'displ'

mpg %>% mutate(manufacturer = fct_reorder(manufacturer, order_var))
#> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: length(f) == length(.x) is not TRUE.
```

Tried with `bang bang !!`:

```
mpg %>% mutate(manufacturer = fct_reorder(manufacturer, !!order_var))
#> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: length(f) == length(.x) is not TRUE.
```

Tried with `eval`:

```
as.name(eval(order_var))
#> displ

mpg %>% mutate(manufacturer = fct_reorder(manufacturer, as.name(eval(order_var))))
#> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: length(f) == length(.x) is not TRUE.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah solved

```
mpg %>% mutate(manufacturer = fct_reorder(manufacturer, .[[order_var]]))
```